# Autodesk EAGLE: PCB layout lost when copying from schematic

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, eaglecad

On one panel, I'd like to have 4x4 'boards' that are all the same. When I copy the respective 'group' in EAGLE, I am losing the placement of the components with respect to each other in the PCB layout. How can I fix that?

Comment: Look into "panelization".  PCB fabs do this to maximize the number of PCB's they can manufacture using one sheet of PCB material(s).  It can be done manually by you (you can design your own panel if you like (we do all the time)).  Some cad programs call this an "Embedded Board Array".  The point is that your request is not uncommon.  However, I personally do not know how it's done in Eagle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because each new group you create (by copying), renumbers the parts in the new group, your software will not recognize that the old PCB copper patterns you created for the original parts have any relationship with the new renumbered parts. Net names will also change and basically you can't expect your software to read your mind.

If you want to have multiple versions of the same board you should probably edit the Gerber files or use your PCB fabrication house to do this task.

Comment: thank you, my manufacturer offers to make a panel so I have one solution, which is enough for me.